# Jquery condition to replace title tags

Tags: jquery, tags, replace, title, alt

I have been scratching my head trying to get Jquery to conditionally search and replace title tags in a document. Essentially I want Jquery to go through a list of image tags, check if the image tag is a space " " and if so remove the space "". If the title tag is anything else Jquery should leave it alone.

HTM i am not allowed to add code so I put it here http://www.stylishtimes.com/title.txt

So far I can remove every title tag with:`$('#galleria img').attr("title", "");`

Thanks in Advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#galleria img[title=" "]').attr('title','');
```

Comment: +1 I totally missed the point. Didn't notice the *is a space* part of the question. Somehow I read *has a space* instead. This would be a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var title = $('#galleria img').attr("title");
var newtitle = $.trim(title);
$('#galleria img').attr("title", newtitle);
```